# Is there any way to modify a request in Traefik?

Tags: traefik

Does Traefik have a way to insert a plugin or a hook that will allow me to modify a request before passing it on to a backend?

I would like to add an additional header into the request that the backend services will need to consume.

It is not a static header, so I will need to be able to plug in code somehow in order to execute our own business logic to generate this header.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the Traefik Slack group:

> Daniel Tomcej: No, traefik currently does not have dynamic header modification
>   -- https://traefik.slack.com/archives/C0CDT22PJ/p1534188045000322?thread_ts=1534187995.000430&cid=C0CDT22PJ

edit:

However I found this pull request merged that allows headers to be forwarded from the auth server response to the backend server:

https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/3521/files